# Why Dockerfile builds but is not working correctly, even though it works manually?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I've been trying to get this running for many MANY hours. I've been scouting docker docs, github repos and other stuff but I can't get it working for some reason.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM mattrayner/lamp:latest-1804

WORKDIR /app
RUN  wget -O /tmp/lwt.zip http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/lwt/lwt_v_1_6_3.zip && \
     yes A | unzip /tmp/lwt.zip &&\
     rm /tmp/lwt.zip &&\
     mv connect_xampp.inc.php connect.inc.php
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

It build normally without any errors but when I run the image nothing appears in the `/app` directory and I get just a basic *Welcome to LAMP* view on my browser.

Though,

If I do `docker run -p "80:80" -it -v ${PWD}/app:/app mattrayner/lamp:latest-1804 /bin/bash`, `cd /app`, copy and paste

```sh
wget -O /tmp/lwt.zip http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/lwt/lwt_v_1_6_3.zip && \
     yes A | unzip /tmp/lwt.zip &&\
     rm /tmp/lwt.zip &&\
     mv connect_xampp.inc.php connect.inc.php
```

it still doesn't work **BUT** if I exit and run the same `docker run` command it works.

[Docker LAMP](https://github.com/mattrayner/docker-lamp) instructions also state to do exactly as I have done:

```
FROM mattrayner/lamp:latest-1804

# Your custom commands

CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

As I followed these instructions I thought that everything would work nicely.

What's the catch here? It has something to do with the intermediate containers probably but I can't comprehend it (I'm not a devops or developer by trade, just a hobbyist).

Comment: Please, mark as solved, not only vote up :) Many thanksss :D

Answer (score 4):

That happens because you're doing this:

1. Download a file (wget ...) in your `/app` dir in your docker image.
2. After that, you're overwritting this `/app` dir when you mount volume, with content of your $PWD/app.

If you are installing something doing `docker build` in some dirs, don't mount into the same path.

If you need something in the same path, you can mount some concrete files, but not the whole dir, or it will override what you had in your docker image when container is created.

You can do wget somewhere else or download it into your ${PWD}/app and then mount it.

Comment: In addition to this good answer, you can use `unzip /tmp/lwt.zip -d "/app/` to specify the destination of your unzip. You are basically wgetting the file in tmp and then deleting the tmp directory.

Comment: As I understand I have to put data inside /app at runtime and not a buildtime? How'd I do it in my case? Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: You can do both things, but if you put data in buildtime and runtime, take care and mount in runtime only files you need, not all volume `/app` to avoid unwanted overwritting.